# Spring boot + Angularjs + 3rd party resources

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application. My AngularJS app is placed in the src/main/resources/static folder. I want to interact with a 3rd party application. This requires

1. Load an external JS from cdn
2. Use their JS SDK to connect to their REST APIs.

Issue is

1. Added the external JS in index.html. But on loading it gives following error

   `Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".`

Added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src  <cdn-domain> 'self';">` but issue persists.

2. Suppose I download the js, the above error goes away. But when I try to hit the API using the custom JS, again requests get blocked(same error, different domain).

Please suggest what can be done.